Revert this whitespace change
I seem to have a whitespace change in Git, but I can't revert it. I copied the content on the left-hand side and pasted it in my code in VS Code, but it doesn't detect any changes. How to revert this specific file? I don't want to revert my entire commit. Please see the picture below. 

Is this project worked on different machines (Windows and Linux/MacOS)?

@dani-vta Yes. It's a CRLF/LF issue, right?

yes, it is. I have posted an answer to help you with it.

@dani-vta Thanks for your answer. I have set core.autocrlf to true before but I keep seeing this issue from time to time again. I guess it's coming from other teammates who haven't made this configuration.

yes, everybody in the team has to properly configure their local repository with the appropriate core.autocrlf configuration like I have explained in my answer.

This is simple to do with an interactive rebase:
# Assuming no modified files
git rebase --interactive --rebase-merges $COMMIT_ID_TO_PARENT_OF_THE_PROBLEMATIC_COMMIT
...
# Change "pick" to "edit" in todo-list and exit editor
...
dos2unix your/file/with/wrong/eol.json              # or unix2dos if applicable
git add your/file/with/wrong/eol.json
git rebase --continue

In case of conflicts, resolve using KDiff3.

Since you've confirmed in the comments that you're developing on different machines, it seems like that your issue lies in the line ending character. In fact, Windows machines use two characters to mark the end of a line (carriage return and line feed), while Linux-based OS use only one character (line feed).
To fix your problem, you need to configure the core.autocrlf variable to true in repositories on Windows machines.
# repo on a Windows machine
git config --global core.autocrlf true

While to input in repositories on Linux-based machines.
# repo on a Linux based machine
git config --global core.autocrlf input

Like so, with core.autocrlf set to true, when a file is added to the repository on a Windows machine, Git automatically converts the CRLF characters into a single LF character. Likewise, when a file is checked out on a Windows machine, Git automatically converts the single line ending LF into CRLF, matching the line ending of the OS.
Instead, on Linux-based machines, line endings are already marked with a single LF character, so entered values are already fine. However, if a file with CRLF endings is accidentally introduced into the repository, Git will automatically convert the CRLF into a single LF, matching the way how line endings are inserted on the machine (that's why the value is called input).
Keep in mind that if your files have already been committed to the repository with a CRLF line ending, you will have to commit them again with only LF as the end of line. This is because you need to bring your repository to a state where only the LF character marks the end of a line, so that repositories on Windows machines can automatically operate the conversion, while other OS will simply read and write.
Here, I'm also attaching a link to Formatting and Whitespace from the Git documentation for further reading.
